# How to convert array of strings into JSON object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, vue.js

I need to go back to a list page without lose the filters criteria. To do this, I'm using cookies, setting it when the form filter is submitted.
In the list page mounted hookie, I'm getting the specific cookie as a string, using the split method and i have the result:

```
[
 "filter1:value",
 "filter2:value"
]
```

Or, an array of strings. How can i convert it to JSON to manipulate and insert each value in v-model of form filter?

*Is a web application using VueJS.

Comment: Why not save it as a JSON string instead?

Comment: As an array its already an "object". Do you want to convert the array to a json string?

Comment: Ok I see on re-reading. Use `JSON.parse()`

Comment: You likely don't want to convert it to JSON. You probably want to convert it to an object. JSON is a text format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Object.fromEntries` to construct an object out of your array elements after splitting them using `:` seperator:

```js
let data = [
 "filter1:value",
 "filter2:value"
]

let result = Object.fromEntries(data.map(e => e.split(":")))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the first row we convert array to string, with the second row we convert String, to JSON object, you can manipulate

```
var arrayToString = JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, arr));  // convert array to string
var stringToJsonObject = JSON.parse(arrayToString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **JSON.stringify and JSON.parse**.

```
JSON.stringify({list: ["filter1:value", "filter2:value"]})
'{"list":["filter1:value","filter2:value"]}'
JSON.parse('{"list":["filter1:value","filter2:value"]}')
{list: ["filter1:value", "filter2:value"]}
```